# Where should MongoDB be installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: mongodb, macos

When installing MongoDB Community Edition (3.6) on MacOS (version 10.13.2 High Sierra), the instructions state in Step 3 to "Copy the extracted archive to the target directory (or the location from which MongoDB will run)".

Which directory should be used as the target directory?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the extracted archive to a new directory as suggested in step 3 (per the instructions on [docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)), use the mv command in the terminal (be sure to replace the name of your folder in the following command below):

`sudo mv mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.6.3 /usr/local/mongodb`.

This command will rename the folder "mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.6.3" to "mongodb" and move it to the location /usr/local/. Sudo must be used to move it to this location and will require your password.

Here's a step-by-step video: [How to install MongoDB on Mac OS X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DX15WbKidXY)